# How can java create objects with children of the same type without recursion?

Tags: java

This might be a very obvious question but I can not quite wrap my head around it.

I was starting to implement my own tree structure and figured that each node needs to have its parent/children saved somewhere inside itself. Below is a simplified version of the code:

```
public class Container {
  public String name;
  public String type;
  public Container child;

  public Container(String name, String type){
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
  }
  public void createChild(String name, String type){
    this.child = new Container(name, type);
  }
}
```

The question is how can this line `Container child;` and `this.child = new Container(name, type);` work?

To me it seems like a chicken-and-egg problem, this is the class where the object is defined but it can still preemptively hold an object of itself, and if this is the case then the object it holds should hold its own child and so on. This leads to (in my mind) a recursive problem when trying to allocate memory for the Container objects.

Comment: Although this can be viewed as a sort of tree, because it has only one child it's more like a linked list.

Comment: Yes I just cut down on the structure when linking the example, the principle was the same :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Container child` declaration does not construct a `Container` instance; it just *declares a field that can be used to refer to a `Container`*, but the reference is initially `null`. So you do not enter into recursion.

Comment: So it does not have any information about what a Container object contains?

Comment: @asiew No, it just knows how to reach the child `Container`, if any.

Answer (score 8):

There is no recursion in the code you display.

The constructor assigns the `name` and `type` fields as parametrized with.

The `createChild` uses the constructor for a new instance of the `Container` class, which is then assigned to the current `Containter`'s instance's `child` variable.

Constructor recursion is when a constructor invokes itself at the first line, or when a circular call is detected (contructor A invoking constructor B, invoking constructor A again), neither of which would compile.

**Worth noting**

**IF** you invoked `createChild` within your constructor, **then** you would have (bad) recursion and your code would likely fail with a JVM error (most probably a `StackOverflowError`, but as [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) mentions it could also be an `OutOfMemoryError`).

That is because the constructor would recursively invoke itself, and the compiler is not "clever" enough to detect that, hence it would pass compilation but fail at runtime.

Comment: Worth noting, indeed

Comment: I think I got confused with the 'Container child;' declaration, I assumed that it contained some information about what a Container object was.

Comment: @asiew as illustrated in another answer, the HAS-A relationship between an instance of a class and another instance of the same class does not qualify as recursion. Essentially there's nothing preventing a `Container` instance from having an instance variable also of type `Container`. Problems can occur with non-controlled recursive idioms as illustrated.

Comment: It would not be guaranteed to fail with a `StackOverflowError`, it would also possible to fail with an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: @Holger I think I understand your point - i.e. too many objects in the heap, but wouldn't a `StackOverflowError` occur **before** an `OutOfMemoryError` in this case?

Comment: There is no guaranty about how many recursion levels a particular implementation can handle, it could even be infinite due to tail call optimizations. It’s also possible that an implementation supports dynamic stack expansion, so a recursion could run until there is no more RAM for the stack available, in this case, the implementation is free to decide whether it will throw `StackOverflowError` or `OutOfMemoryError`; both is correct. Also, the maximum amount of RAM is unspecified. You could configure a JRE to an extrem small value…

Answer (score 0):

Other answers have correctly identified that no recursion occurs because the constructor doesn't fill in the child field. However they haven't specifically addressed:

> This leads to (in my mind) a recursive problem when trying to allocate
>   memory for the Container objects.

There is no memory allocation for the object which child references (since it is a null reference) which is why your class doesn't result in recursion when you first construct an instance of it.

Comment: There is a memory allocation, a declared object is a pointer to somewhere, in this case to null, but the pointer itself still needs memory

Comment: You're right of course, I've edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must know that we are talking here about a **HAS-A relationship** :

> Has-A means an instance of one class “has a” reference to an instance
>   of another class or another instance of same class.

Even it's the same class but there will be two different instance in the memory (in your case) or maybo three or more ...

[image]

In your case the most importing thing to khow to resolve this comprehension issue is the sequence of constructor call.

1- Container constructor (The wrapper container is created)

2- ChildContainer constructor (The child container is created and the relation **HAS-A** is setted)

Answer (score 0):

> The question is how can this line `Container child;`  and `this.child =
>    new Container(name, type);` work?

Because it is the [recursive data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type) and Java lets you do that.